# Informix - Create a Foreign key while creating Table

Tags: foreign-keys, informix

I can see the documentation in IBM page here :

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0103.htm#ids_sqs_0103

But when I try the following, I get an error :

```
CREATE TABLE relacion_Usuarios_pertenecen_Instituto
 (
  foranea_CI_usuario  REFERENCES Usuarios CI,
  foranea_id_instituto  REFERENCES Institutos id_instituto,
  PRIMARY KEY (foranea_CI_usuario,foranea_id_instituto)
 );
```

#### Error I get :

```
  201: A syntax error has occurred.
Error in line 77
Near character position 29
```

Line 77 is the 2nd line of my snippet.

I have tried different combinations of possible syntaxes, and always i have an generic "syntax error".

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jonathan said, the syntax you are using is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
--drop table if exists usuarios;
create table Usuarios (CI int UNIQUE);
--drop table if exists institutos;
create table Institutos (id_instituto int UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE relacion_Usuarios_pertenecen_Instituto
 (
  foranea_CI_usuario INT REFERENCES Usuarios (CI),
  foranea_id_instituto  INT REFERENCES Institutos (id_instituto),
  PRIMARY KEY (foranea_CI_usuario,foranea_id_instituto)
 );
```

The following page contains a basic referential constraint example:

- [Single column referential constraint examples](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0523.htm)

Comment: @MatiasBarrios You should also consider naming your constraints, like foreign keys and primary keys, so any error message relating to them is easier to understand, instead of having to track down the objects ID's int the catalog tables.

Comment: Im already naming my constraints in the Usuarios and Institutos table. Can you tell me exactly what I should name in this table?

Comment: @MatiasBarrios Check my answer, it expands upon J_S, adding named constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Based on J_S example, you can also name the constraints in the `relacion_usuarios_pertenecen_instituto` table, using the Informix SQL sintaxe:

```sql
CREATE TABLE usuarios 
(
    ci INTEGER UNIQUE CONSTRAINT usuarios_un1
);

CREATE TABLE institutos 
(
    id_instituto INTEGER UNIQUE CONSTRAINT institutos_un1
);

CREATE TABLE relacion_usuarios_pertenecen_instituto
(
    foranea_ci_usuario INTEGER REFERENCES usuarios (ci) CONSTRAINT relacion_usuarios_pertenecen_instituto_fk1
    , foranea_id_instituto  INTEGER REFERENCES institutos (id_instituto) CONSTRAINT relacion_usuarios_pertenecen_instituto_fk2
    , PRIMARY KEY (foranea_ci_usuario, foranea_id_instituto) CONSTRAINT relacion_usuarios_pertenecen_instituto_pk
);
```

You can use your preferred method for creating the constraints names. I am using the table name and then appending a suffix to differentiate its type: _pk for `PRIMARY KEY`, _fk# for `FOREIGN KEY`, etc. It becomes a bit verbose, but Informix identifiers can go up to 128 Bytes ([Identifier](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1660.htm#ids_sqs_1660)) (`dbaccess` is a bit limited for showing long names).

Answer (score 1):

If you list the columns you are referencing, the referenced column name(s) should be enclosed in parentheses (which could contain a comma-separated list of column names).

If your foreign key references the primary key of the other table, it is sufficient to specify the name of the referenced table.

(Also, note that the CREATE TABLE statements in the question have omitted the data types of the columns in the table — that yields a generic syntax error.)

Thus, you could use:

```
CREATE TABLE relacion_Usuarios_pertenecen_Instituto
(
    foranea_CI_usuario    INTEGER NOT NULL
                          REFERENCES Usuarios(CI) CONSTRAINT f1_relacion_usarios_pertencen_instituto,
    foranea_id_instituto  INTEGER NOT NULL
                          REFERENCES Institutos   CONSTRAINT f2_relacion_usarios_pertencen_instituto,
    PRIMARY KEY (foranea_CI_usuario, foranea_id_instituto)
    CONSTRAINT pk_relacion_usarios_pertencen_instituto
);
```

The first of these explicitly references the `CI` column of the `Usuarios` table, which doesn't have to be the primary key of that table (but if it is not the primary key, it must have a unique constraint on the key).  The second doesn't specify the columns (any more; the column was specified in the question), assuming that the `id_instituto` column of the `Institutos` table is in fact the primary key of that table.

Note that you can have a multi-column primary key, and hence any foreign keys that reference that primary key will be multi-column foreign keys.  It is often better to avoid such keys and to use an 'ID' column (often based on either the SERIAL or BIGSERIAL types) as the primary key.  It is then important to enforce a uniqueness constraint on the multi-column key, making it into an alternative key.

- [REFERENCES clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0103.htm)